# META-INF/com/google/android/update-binary source code?

Tags: android-source, edify

In the `update.zip` of android update file `update-binary` executable files is present in the path `META-INF/com/google/android/`. The `update.zip` will be downloaded by the system and later update will be installed in the system. I need help in understanding the `update-binary` file and its uses. Can any body help me out with this as well as the corresponding source code? It will be good if any body share the source code link.

Comment: [Here](http://marakana.com/s/post/1065/updating_android_os_via_ota) is a nice tutorial from marakana group. In this tutorial the author explains how to create OTA (over-the-air) updates and provides some knowledge about the components.

Answer (score 7):

This script language is called Edify and the update-binary code is here:

- https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_bootable_recovery/tree/jellybean/edify

More about it:

- http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc:_About_Edify